# How to limit 5 location call backs and set one marker in android studio with Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm using Google Map with Android to get Location based services.
I need to point out only 5 accurate locations (current location) and set a marker to the most accurate location point.
I have used the following code to add the marker, but it repeatedly add markers to the map.
So i need only to get one marker to the most accurate location.

```java
Marker currentPosition = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
   .position(new LatLng(arg0.getLatitude(), arg0.getLongitude()))
   .snippet("Value"));
```

Comment: Instead of setting 5 marker, why don't you try first calc their avg. and then set one marker on the map.

Comment: Hi @bjiang , Any code snippet related that